# How to search similar image in my web site

Tags: html

I have some picture in my web site, when I use google to search the image, it just show All images in the cloud, can it search under my web site only?

Answer (score 0):

You can search a specific site with `site:`

**For example:** to search Facebook, you would type `site:facebook.com`

And for your site, you can search by image and add in the search bar: `site:yoursite.com`

Comment: I have tried it but still cannot search image. I have already show all images using two pages, one is asp another is html .When I input site: my web site, I cannot found my images which I have upload few days ago。 How to fix it?